# Android Emulator for Visual Studio White Screen

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator, visual-studio-emulator

Recently the emulator only shows a blank white screen instead of the known UI.

But in the preview image on the taskbar, that one which shows up when you hover with the mouse over it, shows the UI again.

How can i resolve this "Blank Screen" problem?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Same problem!! Anybody have found a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a virtual machine, turn off the flag "Accellerate 3D Ghraphic" inside virtual machine settings. Start again virtual machine and you should see the emulator correctly